# Why does printf work differently with sudo?

Tags: bash, sudo, linux

I have a simple script to convert a text file with colour escape sequences to the actual characters.
It works if I run it directly, but not with sudo.

To set up the scripts:

**test.txt**

```
\e[1;34mTEST\e[0m\n
```

**test.sh** (+x)

```
printf "`cat $1`" > test.bin
```

- Running `./test.sh test.txt` then `cat test.bin` gives `TEST` in blue.
- Running `sudo ./test.sh test.txt` then `cat test.bin` gives `\e[1;34mTEST\e[0m\n`

What's going on here?

Notes:

- Running `sudo bash -c "./test.sh test.txt"` gives the right output - why is that?
- `echo -e` behaves the same as `printf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sudo -i ./test.sh`.

I don't know if there's there a specific need for having the colour coded string in a separate file then writing it out to another one, but the following works fine withou the `-i` flag:

```
#!/bin/bash
string="\e[1;34mTEST\e[0m\n"
printf "${string}"
```

Comment: Cool, that works - I'm interested in why it's happening as much as workaround though

Comment: BTW it's in a separate file because there are several different strings, each about 20 KB

Comment: I believe it has to do with TERM settings.  Usually by default `sudo` has `Defaults env_reset` set in its configuration.  When you're calling the script via sudo those settings are missing.  By using `sudo -i` or `sudo bash -c "..."` they are being set.